# React-Native WebView and data url from Firebase on android

Tags: android, react-native

I'want to open a web view with a pdf since my db on Firebase :

```
displayCharte(){
        firebase.database().ref('/config/settings/tuning/charte/users').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        let userData = (snapshot.val()) || 'Anonymous';
        this.setState({
            charteUrl: userData
        });
    });
}
```

And that's my render :

```
render() {
        return (
                <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                    <WebView
                            source={{uri: this.state.charteUrl}}
                            style={styles.pdf}
                            startInLoadingState={true}
                            javaScriptEnabled={true}
                            domStorageEnabled={true}
                            startInLoadingState={true}

                    />
```

it's works perfectly works on ios but not on android....
And when i make the url directly on the "source" it's the same.....
With an other url like 'https://fr-fr.facebook.com/' the webView appear so it's the url from firebase was not correctly formated ?

Comment: Could you show us the URL? `console.log(userData)` in your `displayCharte()` func.

Comment: sure : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mkmoney-cef37.appspot.com/o/config%2Fsettings%2Ftuning%2Fcharte%2Fla-peche-statuts-v3.pdf?alt=media&token=67a4e47e-387d-4739-aca8-095c8b6d5435"

Comment: Try setting the source on your WebView as source={{uri: \`https://${this.state.charteUrl}\`}}

Comment: @Dan nope , it doesn't work

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to encode the url, something like this :

encodeURIComponent(${this.state.charteUrl});


try  this and here is the link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent